# Allow CRM 2011 to access from external server

Tags: port, crm

I have set up a CRM 2011 in a vmware under port 5555. I can access the CRM system fine locally. However, when I tried accessing from my host machine I got IE cannot display webpage error. I can access IIS port 80 though. I have added Inbound Rule to TCP port 5555 on my Windows Server 2008 R2 CRM server. Anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anything such as no-ip, dyndns?
You have to make sure your router is mapped to route the port: 5555 to your server Ip, is your internet with static IP?

Hope that helps.

Renato

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post however might help someone...
You need to allow port 5555 on your VPC (VMWare)
Go to Firewall settings and add exception for this port. Once done you should be able to access CRM externally.

Below is a detailed blog about it
http://rokhri.com/blog/crm-how-to-access-crm-externally-installed-on-vpc/